# Client to client communication - prevent user from seeing the contents

Tags: c#, json, encryption, aes, multiplayer

I am developing a simple turn based game (a bit like board game). I decided to implement a simple PBEM (Play-by EMail) system for multiplayer. The system uses JSON to transmit each player actions.

In a case of 3 players, the system works like this:

- Player1 makes his actions and sends them (as JSON) to Player 2
- Player2 reads the JSON, than he appends his own moves and then sends the JSON to Player 3
- Player3 reads the JSON, makes his own moves and then sends a new JSON to Player 1

I want that my app on all 3 player computers can open and read the json, but the players themselves should not be able to read the contents of the .json (they could gain an advantage and that would be cheating).

In order to prevent the players from reading the JSON , right now I encrypt the .json files [using AES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-5.0).

The problem is my key used to encrypt/decrypt is hardcoded in the app.

So right now everything works, .jsons are encrypted but as soon as my app binaries were to be reverse engineered the key used for encryption would be visible and everyone could use it to decrypt the .jsons.

How do I solve this problem ?

P.S Note that the communication is entirely client to client based, there are no servers or user managment.

Edit: Title modified a bit.

Comment: P2P communication and security isn't trivial. You can't just make a connection and encrypt it. BTW secure communication is a solved problem with HTTPS. JSON doesn't play a role at all. In fact, if you used gRPC you'd get far better performance. The *real* issues are authenticating players, broadcasting status, preventing cheats etc. There's a reason almost all online games use a server. DirectX on Windows had a P2P component BUT the latency over a WAN was too high even for strategy games like Age of Empries

Comment: In fact, P2P and cloud computing grew together: How do you handle communications in a *data center* when you can't trust the servers, or can't have *one* trusted server? How do you distribute the state of eg files or blobs to all servers and get back correct data when any of them can fail at any time? Over a WAN?

Comment: One could say `distributed players, no trust, Bitcoin!` except even this problem was solved by all online games 20 years ago. You can modify the game rules so it doesn't matter if everyone sees the overall stat of the *previous* round. Or each peer can only store its own state and only non-sensitive overall state. All peers have to validate any state changes to ensure there's no cheating. You'll have to handle out-of-order or delayed actions anyway.

Comment: Why don't you just use WCF.  There is a P2P feature in it not to mention security

Comment: You should describe when the different turns are supposed to be read. Based on your description the turns are just created but never processed.

Answer (score 0):

> as soon as my app binaries were to be reverse engineered the key used for encryption

You cannot do much about it. The encryption ensures confidentiality against a 3rd party actor, but the client is actually.. a client and needs to decrypt and process the data.

You can try to hide the key somewhere and make it harder to find it (obfuscation), but at the end the app runs on the client side and needs to have the key somewhere.

> everyone could use it to decrypt the .jsons.

You may use PKI (ech player would have its own private/piblic key pair) and they would exchange their public keys. This way only the recipient would be able to decrypt the message.

Answer (score 0):

I think PKI infrastructure will resolve your issue but **this is a very expensive solution** for this use case.

Instead of thinking about reverse engineering, you should **think about access control measures**. Your application should lock the JSON data file once player1 sends information to player2. An application must lock the file so that no other program or user can open it for reading or writing.

Here we should ask the question to use case first. Nobody can give a guarantee for internal threats.

Answer (score 0):

Does your app really need to know the entire game state? The best way to keep a secret is not to tell anyone until they need to know.

For example, each player could write their game state locally, then hash it and only share the hash for that turn with other players. Later they could provide the full game state to other players to verify that they didn't cheat.

What technique you use depends on how your game works and how much information you actually need to share.